# How do i get cefpython3 on Raspberry pi 3 A+

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cefpython

Trying to get cefpython3 installed on raspberry pi 3 A+, but I'm getting a little bit lost in all of the download / build directions.
simply using `pip install cefpython3=66.0` doesnt seem to cut it.
I am new to linux so some of the commands i feel are implied or second nature for experienced linux users, which is a little beyond me atm. help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try to install it? Perhaps you need to install `python3-pip`?

Comment: @ti7 If i run `python3 -m pip install cefpython3==66.0` 

I will get

`Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cefpython3==66.0
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cefpython3==66.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `cefpython3` doesn't support the Raspberry Pi's ARM processor (yet), so this simply won't work without troublesome hacks like [x86 emulation](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86)

There's no published ARM packages (though you could perhaps build it yourself) https://pypi.org/simple/cefpython3/

However, there's explicit reference to this being a future/missing feature on GitHub

- Work ticket for adding the feature
  *Support for ARM platforms like Chromebook and Raspberry Pi. Support for Android.*
  https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/projects/7
- Some Issues/Pull Requests related to the feature https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/issues?q=arm

Comment: Question about x86 emulation. so I am building a kivy program that uses cefpython to embed a browser - If i develop this on my 64 bit-windows machine and then somehow build it for x86 linux using pyinstaller, could I use the x86 emulator to run that program on my pi? Just looking for the path forward

Comment: This is a constant source of trouble, and while there's an army of paid stuff clamoring to help you make builds .. frankly, if you're set on using Windows, I'd look to using an i686 Linux VM for any 32-bit Linux compiles. If you're looking for something _very_ advanced, you could build a complete test system with [Gentoo's crossdev](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Cross_build_environment), make (whole OS) builds that target the RPi, and test with QEMU and the real device. This will work in a VM too, but it'll be extremely resource-hungry https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Distributions_based_on_Gentoo